# How to set PHP Cookie Pixel using img tag

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to save cookie using img tag. I used img tag in thankyou.php and wrote cookie related code in pixel.php file.

These three files are in the same directory(Folder Name: landing).

Here is index.php file code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="thankyou.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is thankyou.php file code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>You've successfully subscribed for this campaign.</h3>

<img alt="" width="1" height="1" style="display:none" src="pixel.php?e=<?= $_GET['email'] ?>&c=book_bonus_video_1" />

</body>
</html>
```

Here is pixel.php file code.

```
$sCampaign = @ $_GET['c'];
$sCampaign = urldecode($sCampaign);
$sEmail = @ $_GET['e'];
$sEmail = urldecode($sEmail);
setcookie('campaign_' . $sCampaign,strtolower($sEmail),time()+60*60*24*365,'/');
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
die(base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAJAAAP8AAAAAACH5BAUQAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICBAEAOw=='));
```

When I submit form(index.php), thankyou.php page is opened but cookie is not created. But when i write URL ( http://www.example.com/landing/pixel.php?e=user@email.com&c=book_bonus_video_1 ) in browser it creates cookie.

I don't know where is issue in my code.
Thanks in advance for guiding me.

Comment: Have you checked the `thankyou.php` source? (I mean generated source)

Comment: Maybe the problem is within a path (URL) to pixel.php, it seems you have this in the same directory as thankyou.php, but in example you use `landing`

Comment: try with setcookie('campaign_' . $sCampaign,strtolower($sEmail),time()+60*60*24*365,'/','example.com'); //add domain name in last parameter

Comment: Thanks @saty,  but I have also tried domain name, as you mentioned.
setcookie('campaign_' . $sCampaign,strtolower($sEmail),time()+60*60*24*365,'/','example.com');

Comment: instead of this example.com use your domain name of site

Comment: Unclear stuff: 1) Have you checked whether `setcookie()` returns true or false? 2) How have you verified the generated header and whether the cookie has been set?

Comment: Thanks @saty,
Obviously, example.com is only for display at stackoverflow.com. I'm using my own domain name.

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroG.Vicario,
What do you mean by "generated header"?

Comment: after change domain name is this working for you

Comment: Alright... Open the browser console (you can hit `F12` in many browsers) and head to a tab called "Network" or something similar. Reload the page and find the call to `pixel.php`. In the *response* pane you should see HTTP headers and they should include `Set-Cookie` among them. Now, whenever you request a new page, you should see "Cookie" in the *request* pane. As about setcookie's return value, you can inspect it with [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) (you might need to comment out the `header('Content-Type: image/gif');` to avoid the browser hiding it.

Comment: Said that, you're using a terribly convoluted and kind of unrealiable way to set the cookie. You could do it right from `thankyou.php`, there's no need to use a picture as a proxy.

Comment: Your browser may block the cookie request as well as an anti-spam measure. This is to stop tracking cookies you might see in ads. Check your console for more.